# Как на VBA найти в документе Word строки с очень широкими пробелами?

Tags: vba, ms-word, search

Как найти все строки, которые из-за выравнивания по ширине получились с очень широкими пробелами, как на картинке?

[image: Вот такие плохие строки]

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно искать не пробелы (они самые обычные), а причину подобного поведения строки. В частности в данном случае растяжение строки похоже происходит из-за того, что строка заканчивается символом перевода строки (на рисунке обозначено цифрой 2) вместо символа завершения абзаца (обозначено цифрой 1). Сама строка с подобных растяжением помечена стрелкой.

[image: Символы]
Для того, что бы увидеть разницу визуально, включите режим отображения непечатных символов соответствующим значком.

[image: Кнопка отображения непечатных символов]

Если вы хотите искать эти символы программно, через VBA, то символ перевода строки имеет обозначение `vbLf`, а символ абзаца `vbCrLf`

Comment: Нет, это не наш случай. Такие строки получаются например когда далее идет путь к файлу на диске, а ворд не знает где поставить знак переноса. Или если идут названия продуктов заглавными буквами, а перенос в таких словах запрещен.

Поэтому задача именно найти такую некрасивую строку, выделить ее цветом и отправить скрин тех писателю, чтобы он решил, как исправить ситуацию.

И естественно сделать это все автоматически, скриптом на VBA.

Comment: Я конечно выкрутился из ситуации, просто смотрю сколько символов в строке, и если меньше опр. порога выделяю такую строку цветом.
Альтернативное решение - отключить выравнивание по ширине, и построчно смотреть где закончилась строка, и опять же если меньше порога - значит вот она - "плохая" строчка.
Но хотелось бы более красивого решения :)

Answer (score 0):

```
' Поиск строк с низкой заполненностью
Sub CheckLowFillLines()
  Dim Doc As Document
  Set Doc = ActiveDocument
  Dim WordApp As Application
  Set WordApp = Application

  LowFillThreshold = 61

  Dim R1 As Range
  Set R1 = Doc.GoTo(wdGoToLine, wdGoToFirst)
  R1.Select
  WordApp.Selection.Expand wdLine

  Do While WordApp.Selection.MoveDown(wdLine, 1) = 1
    WordApp.Selection.Expand wdLine
    If R1.Start = WordApp.Selection.Range.Start And R1.End = WordApp.Selection.Range.End Then
      Exit Do
    End If
    Set R1 = WordApp.Selection.Range

    If WordApp.Selection.Tables.Count <> 0 Then
      WordApp.Selection.Tables(1).Select
      WordApp.Selection.Collapse (0)
    Else
      If WordApp.Selection.Characters.Last <> Chr(13) And WordApp.Selection.Characters.Count < LowFillThreshold Then
        If WordApp.Selection.Paragraphs.Alignment = 3 Then ' wdAlignParagraphJustify
          LineNumber = WordApp.Selection.Information(10) 'wdFirstCharacterLineNumber)
          PageNumber = WordApp.Selection.Information(1) ' wdActiveEndPageNumber
          StdErr.WriteLine "Low fill factor in line = " & LineNumber & " on page = " & PageNumber
          FileName = ErrorFileNamePrefix & "Малое заполнение строки на странице " & PageNumber & ", строка " & LineNumber & ".pdf"
          WordApp.Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
          Call ExportPageAsPdf(Doc, FileName)
          Doc.Undo
        End If
      End If
    End If
  Loop
End Sub
```